# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - USB flash drive doesn't appear in the launcher

Tags: usb-drive

Please,can someone help my to understand why a TDK USB flash drive doesn't appear in the launcher.

I formatted it with "disks"utility and when I plug it in,I can see it (in disks utility).

But I need to copy same files into the USB and if it doesn't appear I can't.Or,are there other ways to copy my files?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the output of `lsblk`?

Answer (score 10):

Using Gnome Disks to format clears the USB drive, but doesn't create a new partition. To create a new one:

1. `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` (make sure the usb drive is /dev/sdb, it looks like it based on your output of `lsblk`)

Type <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>

2. Now format the new partition with `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1`

Your USB drive should now appear under the file manager

Answer (score 0):

Your flash drive, if mounted, should be located `/media/$name/` . If you did not mount the drive you can do so in the "Disks" utility by pressing the play button after selecting the partition, or normally by opening it on the sidebar in the Unity desktop. You can also use the mount command, but I assume you are using a GUI.

Comment: I'm not expert at all.Please,probably it's unmounted,to know that have I to check in /media/$name/?True "normally by opening it on the sidebar..."this is my problem it doesn't appear on the sidebar as usual,why?What is a GUI?and if I'm using it,can I mount it just from "Disks"utility?Thank you

Comment: I think Evan Chen is correct that you reformatted without re-partitioning the drive. That is why it does not show up on the sidebar. GUI is an acronym for graphical user interface which is a graphic based symbol environment such as the unity desktop instead of a solely word based environment such as the bash terminal or command line.