# Error formatting volume: No such file or directory

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, disk, format

I was being unable to access my USB drive. After following the instructions listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/917578/588685), I found this response:

`$ sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1`

`mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
/dev/sdb1: No such file or directory`

When I tried to follow the instructions listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/290883/588685), I found the unmount option (and all other options in the menu) in the `Disks` GUI utility to be disabled. So I tried to create a partition using the utility and encountered this error:

> **Error formatting volume**
>
> Error wiping device: Command-line 'wipefs -a "/dev/sdb1"' exited with non- zero exit status 1: wipefs: error: /dev/sdb1: probing initialization failed: No such file or directory  (udisks-error-quark, 0)

I would appreciate suggestions for a way forward from here.

Comment: The instructions you linked don't mention `wipefs`, but anyway, do you have a /dev/sdb1 device? `lsblk` should show your partitions. Or maybe you just needed to add `sudo`?

Comment: @Xen2050, Sorry I forgot to include one of the posts I tried and mistakenly mentioned its response as the response to another post. I have corrected it now. Would you be so kind to go through it once again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved it with help of GParted. All I had to do was reformatting. Following is what I did:

- Install GParted:

  > sudo apt install gparted
- Right click on the disk (which was listed with a red exclamation!)
- Select `Format to`
- Select `ext4`
- Click on the `Apply All Operations` button

That solved it!